# Communicate between two asp.net services with docker on same host

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose

I'm currently trying to host two of my asp.net core services in docker. I am able to get them both up and running but the problem is that I don't know how to communicate between the two containers.

I'm using docker-compose to get my applications up and running and to allocate the ports on my host machine.

The urls to the services are placed in the appsettings.json. I think the problem lies here because I don't know where to get the right IP of the running containers.

I already tried to use the host network in both docker-compose files but I wasn't able to get that working.

I also tried to get the container's IP by using docker container inspect. but those IP's are unreachable.

docker-compose of service 1:

```
version: '3.4'    
services:
  leave.api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app1/Dockerfile
    environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ports:
  - 5002:5002
```

docker-compose of service 2:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  backoffice:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: BackOffice/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
```

I hope to find a way to be able to communicate between the two services.

Answer (score 0):

You could use external_links options, seems the most fit solution in your case:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external_links

Answer (score 0):

This explains bridging containers https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/

If your communication is http based I would recommend having a http gateway that keeps track of your containers and their service endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate between two services in docker container using the name of service.

In your case, you have backoffice and leave.api services in your docker composed file.

So, you can access the backoffice service from leave.api using https://backoffice:5001/.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, but I found another solution that works best for my situation.

I added the following line to both of my docker-compose files:

```
network_mode: bridge
```

This way both of my containers use the same network. After that I could communicate between the containes using my host ip address with the port the service is bound to. I placed this IP in the appsettings.json the same way as I had it before.